# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el color de superposición al abrir el menu de navegación?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

El color al que me refiero es, al momento de abrir el menú de navegación (Navigation Drawer), sobrepone un color de fondo como sombra asumiendo que el menú está abierto y las vistas de fondo se ven por atrás, solamente que quiero ver si es posible modificar el color de ese fondo. Aquí adjunto una imagen del punto al que me refiero. Muchas gracias de ante mano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muestra lo que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Para esto se usa el mètodo

> [setScrimColor(int color)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/drawerlayout/widget/DrawerLayout#setScrimColor(int)) Establezca un color para usar para la
> malla que oscurece el contenido principal mientras un Drawer está
> abierto.

Ejemplo:

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color. holo_blue_bright));
```

Ejemplo:

```
mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por tu respuesta, solo que intenté agregarselo pero al abrir el menu de navegación no se modifica el color, pero agradezco tu respuesta